# How to put two components at right and left of the screen

Tags: react-native

I need to put two components at two ends of the screen. Following is my code.

```
<View style = {{flexDirection:"row"}}>
    <Text>cancel</Text>
    <Text style={{justifyContent:"flex-end",alignItems:"flex-end"}}>cancel</Text>
```

The two buttons are near to each other and I want to push the second button to the extreme right end of the screen without margin, how to do it by properties? It is not working currently. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
<View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
    <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
        <Text>Cancel 1</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:0.5,alignItems:"flex-end"}}> 
        <Text>Cancel 2</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: It worked but still the second text is not at the extreme right